# How can I make a Xamarin Template customizable by passing in a type parameter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the method that I have come up with so far.  However it seems like not such a clean solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could come up with a better solution for doing this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
             x:Class="Japanese.Templates.HeaderTemplate" 
             x:Name="this" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Margin="0">
    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding HeaderType, Converter={StaticResource HeaderType1BoolConverter}, Source={x:Reference this}  }" >
        <!-- code -->
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding HeaderType, Converter={StaticResource HeaderType2BoolConverter}, Source={x:Reference this}  }" >
        <!-- code -->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

In my bank end CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese.Templates
{
    public partial class HeaderTemplate : StackLayout
    {
        public HeaderTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

   public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTypeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(HeaderType),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(DataViewCellTemplate),
            default(string));

    public string HeaderType
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    }
}
```

Converter Code:

```
public class HeaderType1BoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return object.Equals(value, "1");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class HeaderType2BoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return object.Equals(value, "2");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the calling code:

```
<template:HeaderTemplate Header="Application" HeaderType="1" />
```

Comment: Strictly based on the code I see, the value converters aren't needed (you could just expose boolean properties from your template, i.e. `ShowTopContainer` and `ShowBottomContainer`, that would be bound to the `IsVisible` property of each `StackLayout`). Are there any more details you can provide to allow others to better understand what you are trying to achieve with the templates?  Are there other customizations (other than hiding/showing 2 containers) that you would like to make to the templates based on a `HeaderType`.

Comment: Have you considered a Control Template ?

Comment: @Tiago_nes     Can you give me an example of what you mean by a Control Template and how it would fit with my code. Thanks

Comment: @gannaway - I need 3-4 different templates for my application but the outer parts of the templates are all the same.  So I was thinking just to have one template, code in 3-4 different blocks of XAML and pass a parameter or something similar to the template so one of those 3-4 code blocks would show depending on the parameter.

Comment: Would the `HeaderType` be a dynamic value (determined at runtime) or would you know it at design time?  Would you use these templates inside a ListView?

Comment: Here is an example of how to implement a Control Template. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating

Comment: @Tiago_nes - Can you give me an example of how I could use a Control Template for this with the code in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#property-triggers) is an option.

For e.g.: You can add property-triggers to check the value on `HeaderType` and accordingly update the `Content` (or layout) in your custom control `HeaderView`.

*Please note in this case we are extending from `ContentView` not `StackLayout` on the assumption that only one layout/control is visible at a time.*

**XAML**

```
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp" 
    x:Class="SampleApp.HeaderView">

    <ContentView.Triggers>

        <!-- if header type is 1, use header1 layout -->
        <Trigger TargetType="local:HeaderView" Property="HeaderType" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Label Text="Header1" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- if header type is 2, use header2 layout -->
        <Trigger TargetType="local:HeaderView" Property="HeaderType" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Header2" />
                        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Gray" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- you can add more layouts here if you need -->

    </ContentView.Triggers>

    <!-- add default content that can be displayed in case of no match -->
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="DefaultHeader" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Gray" />
    </StackLayout>    

</ContentView>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class HeaderView : ContentView
{
    public HeaderView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTypeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(HeaderType), typeof(string), typeof(HeaderView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string HeaderType
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTypeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:HeaderView HeaderType="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ada, can you tell me will I be able to use that ContentView template inside another StackLayout in the main XAML?

Comment: Yes you can. `<StackLayout><local:HeaderView HeaderType="1" /><!-- other XAML controls -->...</StackLayout>`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking is a ControlTemplate here is an implementation.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="SimpleTheme.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="Header1Template">
                <StackLayout>
                    <!-- code -->
                </StackLayout>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="Header2Template">
                <StackLayout>
                    <!-- code -->
                </StackLayout>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Usage** (This will make header1 your default, you can pick any of the both)

```
<ContentView x:Name="contentView" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource Header1Template}">
```

Now there are many ways to change the header, either by defining as the default code above or with an action which can be a button click like the example given on the link or with a propertyChange event, if you want to depend on a property to choose the header like:

```
public int HeaderNumber { get; set; }

protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    if (propertyName == "HeaderNumber")
    {
        contentView.ControlTemplate = (HeaderNumber == 1) ? Header1Template : Header2Template;
    }
}
```

Note that i never implemented a ControlTemplate but i think this solves your problem.